# Measure the uniformity of a distribution over weekdays

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, uniform-distribution, measurement

I have a similar problem to the question asked here:

[How does one measure the non-uniformity of a distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25827/how-does-one-measure-the-non-uniformity-of-a-distribution)

I have a set of probability distributions over the days of the week. I want to measure how close each distribution is to (1/7,1/7,...,1/7).

At the moment I am using an answer from the above question; an L2-Norm, which has value 1 when the distribution has mass 1 for one of the days, and is minimised for (1/7,1/7,...,1/7). I am linearly scaling this so it lies between 0 and 1, then flipping it so 0 means perfectly non-uniform and 1 means perfectly uniform.

This works pretty well, but I have one issue with it; it treats each weekday equally as a dimension in 7-Dim space, so it doesn't account for the nearness of days; in other words, it gives the same score to (1/2,1/2,0,0,0,0,0) and (1/2,0,0,1/2,0,0,0) even though in some sense the latter is more "spread out" and uniform, and should ideally get a higher score. There is obviously the added complication that the ordering of days is circular.

How can I alter this heuristic to account for the nearness of days?

Comment: Your example of (1/2,1/2,0,0,0,0,0) and (1/2,0,0,1/2,0,0,0) are non-uniform in the same way, so it should not matter if you are only interested in testing for non-uniformity. So maybe you want to test something more that was not stated explicitly in your question? Btw,  [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29) is a measure of uniformity.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I have tried using Entropy but I found the heuristic mentioned above worked better for my purposes. I'm not sure what to call the property of a probability distribution over weekdays that I am interested in, except that it should encapsulate the "spread out-ness" of the probabilities over the week.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [earth mover distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover's_distance), also known as the Wasserstein metric, measures the distance between two histograms. Essentially, it considers one histogram as a number of piles of dirt and then assesses how much dirt one needs to move and how far (!) to turn this histogram into the other. You would measure the distance between your distribution and a uniform one over the days of the week.

This of course accounts for the nearness of days - it's easier to move "dirt" from Monday to Tuesday than from Monday to Thursday, so (1/2,0,0,1/2,0,0,0) would have a lower earth mover distance from the uniform distribution than a histogram that is concentrated on Monday and Tuesday.

What this does *not* do is consider the "circularity" of the week, i.e., that Saturday and Sunday are as close together as are Sunday and Monday. For that, you would need to look for [an earth mover distance defined on *circular* probability mass distributions](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22circular+earth+mover+distance%22). This should be doable using a suitable optimization approach.

---

EDIT: In R, the [`emd` package](http://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/emdist/emd.html) calculates earth mover distances between histograms.

You can address the "circularity" issue in a fairly simple (though ad-hoc) way.

- Calculate an earth mover distance $d_1$ between your distribution and a uniform distibution on Monday through Sunday.
- Calculate a distance $d_2$ against a uniform distribution on Tuesday through Monday.
- Calculate a distance $d_3$ against a uniform distribution on Wednesday through Tuesday.
- ...
- Finally, as the final distance, use the mean of $d_1, \dots, d_7$.

This takes care of the circularity at the expense of a couple of additional calculations.

2nd EDIT: this is *not* the circular earth mover distance as such. For that, you'd need to look through some of the literature [a search will turn up](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22circular+earth+mover+distance%22). If the best way to move dirt between days involves moving it two days from Saturday to Monday, this will show up in five out of the seven $d_i$, but not in the remaining two (where the dirt will need to be moved *five* days).

However, I'd still consider this a potentially useful way to at least consider the circularity in some manner - certainly better than just using a single histogram and defining the week as going from Sunday to Saturday or in some other arbitrary manner. Plus, while some links above turn up implementations for the circular earth mover distance, I'm not aware of one for R, which is probably the most-used language here.

Comment: At first I thought that the latter example (mean of $d_1,\dots,d_7$) is an example of how to calculate the circular earth mover distance and was confused (because the result could be larger than some of $d_i$). Then I realized that this answer doesn't imply that anywhere. I don't know if others read this answer as I did, but it might be good to state it more clearly that the example is not the circular earth mover distance.

Comment: @JiK: good point, and one that also occurred to me after I lost connectivity yesterday. I clarified my answer to emphasize that this is a hack and not real circular earth mover distance.

Comment: Many thanks, in fact I did manage to implement a circular earth mover distance in R with the emd package and emd2d function, by defining my own distance function, so did not need to use the hack that you mentioned. This is exactly what I was looking for! One other trifling matter: What should I call it? As Tim said above, I should not call this uniformity. What would be an appropriate name for this heuristic?

Comment: Well, you *are* testing for uniformity, so that term should be fine. What Tim is arguing about is what specific *departures* from uniformity you want to assess, so you may be looking for a more precise term than "*non*-uniformity". As you discussed, you are not looking for departures in an $L^2$ distance sense, but apparently in an EMD sense. I don't see a good name to call that baby. Perhaps you just want to sprinkle "EMD" across your prose. "Distribution A is more EMD-non-uniform than B." "A is more EMD-distant from uniformity than B." Doesn't sound too poetic, though. Sorry.