# How to measure the 'conservation' in a discrete probability distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, discrete-distributions

I have a discrete probability distribution: [0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.25, 0.6] which represents the probability of a character(given by the index in the vector) to appear.

How can I define a measure between 0 and 1 that shows that most of the probability is concentrated on the last two characters?

Comment: What is the problem in working with the associated probability measure? $\mathbb P(\textrm{first 3 characters} ) = 0.05 \times 3$ and $\mathbb P(\textrm{last 2 characters} ) = 0.25 + 0.6? $

Comment: I wanted a function which can be applied to different probability distributions

Comment: The writing of the question didn't apparently say so. Nevertheless, if you could find insight from another post, then all is okay at the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for is this: [How does one measure the non-uniformity of a distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25827/how-does-one-measure-the-non-uniformity-of-a-distribution)

Entropy is a good measure that differentiates between a uniform distribution (maximum entropy) and a 1 hot encoding (almost 0 entropy).